# Application of fixed point theory in cryptography

Tags: cryptography

Does fixed point theory has an application in Cryptography? I really don't know about Cryptography. If you mention any books on this matter it really helpful

Comment: For a question this broad, surely a google search would turn up something if there was something, right?